# Get list of values of last N match Documents Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB collection where **the last 4 documents** look like this:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('60eb507f9b35c6271434be28'),
  'user_id': '123',
  'name': 'abc',
  'weight': 80}

{'_id': ObjectId('60eb507f9b35c6271434be29'),
  'user_id': '123',
  'name': 'abc',
  'weight': 75}

{'_id': ObjectId('60eb507f9b35c6271434be30'),
  'user_id': '789',
  'name': 'ghi',
  'weight': 88}

{'_id': ObjectId('60eb507f9b35c6271434be31'),
  'user_id': '123',
  'name': 'abc',
  'weight': 80}
```

Using Pymongo, I want to get a list, that will contain the **last 3(most recent) "weight"** values of the **user_id="123" and name="abc"** of my collection. In the above case, the wanted result would be

`[80,75,80]`

I think one condition in my query would be:

`{"$match": {"$and" : [{"user_id": "123"},{"name": abc}]}}`

but i am not sure about the rest.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have parameters like timestamp or creation date something like that in your document?

Comment: Hello sir and thank you for your instant reply! It's possible to add a field of timestamp in that format: ```'tr_timestamp': '11-07-2021 20:10:36'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have timestamp value stored in `tr_timestamp` then you can use `.sort()` and `.limit()` to get you expected output like this:

```
db.collection.find({
      "user_id": "123"
    }).sort({
      "tr_timestamp": -1
    }).limit(3)
```

If you still want to use the `aggregate` pipeline then your query will look like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "user_id": "123",
      "name": "abc"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "tr_timestamp": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 3
  }
])
```

Here is the link to the playground to test your use-case: [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y-ID8oxQh7A)

Also, In `$match` stage there is no need to combine query explicitly in $and as by default behaviour will be the same as $and only so I have removed that part in my query

OR

If you just want a list of weights then your query will look like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "user_id": "123"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "tr_timestamp": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 3
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$user_id",
      "weights": {
        "$push": "$weight"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the link to the playground to test your use-case: [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RMFZrQoqWKt)

Comment: Hello again sir, it worked thanks! One more question. Does the order of the conditions affect aggregate? I mean, what this aggregate gonna do is get the ids that match "123", THEN Sort them descending ,THEN get the last 3 of them? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, order matters in aggregation pipeline. Your understanding is correct